# Variable use in MPI

Tags: mpi

In MPI, if I have the following code will a copy of variable 'a' be created for both the processes or do I have to declare 'a' inside every loop? Or are they both the same?

```
main()
{
 int a;

 if(rank==0)
 {
      a+=1;
 }

 if(rank==1)
 {
   a+=2;
 }

 }
```

Comment: MPI is just a library, so your program is just a regular `C` program, in which MPI tasks are independent processes.

Comment: In MPI there are no shared variables in the sense there are such in OpenMP. Each MPI rank runs in its separate address space and all variables are private unless shared using message passing or RMA windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPI has a **distributed memory programming paradigm**.

To simply put, if you have an application binary (for eg: `hello.out`) and if you run it with an mpi runtime by `mpirun -n 4 hello.out` then what happens is:

It launches 4 instances of the application `hello.out` (we can say it's similar to launching 4 different applications in 4 different nodes). They don't know each other. They execute their own code in their own address spaces. That means, every variables, functions etc belong to it's own instance and not shared with any other processes. So all process has their own variable `a`.

i.e, below code will be called 4 times (if we use `mpirun -n 4`) at same time in different cores/nodes. So, variable `a` will be available in all 4 instances. You can use `rank` to identify your MPI process and manipulates it's value. In below example `a` will store the processes `rank` value. All processes will print `My rank is a` with `a` taking values from `0` to `4`. And only **one** process will print `I am rank 0` since `a==0` will only be `true` for process with `rank 0`.

```
main()
{
 int a;
 int rank;
 MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
 a=rank;
 printf("My rank is %d",a);
 if(a==0)
 {
    printf("I am rank 0");
 }
}
```

So, to interact with each other, the launched processes (eg: `hello.out`) uses MPI (message passing interface) library (as **@Hristo Iliev** commented).

So basically, it's like launching same regular C program on multiple cores/nodes and communicating with each other using message passing (as **Gilles Gouaillardet** pointed in comment  ).